# Pass constructor as callback argument or return value

Tags: c++, constructor, callback

Basically what I'm up to is to make class factory:

```
class SomeClass {
    // Returns subclass of SomeClass by given name, or nullptr
    static SomeClass* childFromString(const std::string&);
}
```

I will use `if...else` to find an actual child class, there will be like 5 of them. But to defer instatiation, I would like to return constructor instead of refference:

```
class SomeClass {
    // This is an attempt to define "returns constructor of SomeClass"
    static (SomeClass)(int) childFromString(const std::string&);
}
```

Which would be used as:

```
SomeClass* = new (SomeClass::childFromString("Child"))(someNumber);
```

This looks totally weird in C++ but is legit in javascript or Java. And I don't think it requires reflection to work, constructor is just a function, right?

So once again, how to pass a **constructor** function as an argument or return value?

Comment: Note that there's many ways to solve my problem without this, but I'm curious about whether it is possible and how to do it. I'm curious how constructor works and this looks like a good exercise to understand more.

Comment: You can't pass or directly call a constructor. Constructors have no names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to call constructor, or return it, or do something with it, since

> Constructors do not have names.

You can either construct objects in function, either returns some function pointer to some creator.

Answer (score 2):

From C++98 Standard 12.1/12 Constructors:

> The address of a constructor shall not be taken.

Constructor is not a "proper" function. Note the same applies to destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a function pointer to a constructor in C++. An ideomatic way would be to return a std::function that defers construction:

```
struct ChildInterface {
     // your interface here
     virtual ~Interface() = default;

};

struct Paul : public Interface {
    // implementation of interface
};


std::function<Interface*()> getDeferedFactoryFor(const std::string& child)
{
     if (child == "paul") {
          return []() {
              return new Paul();
          };
     }
     if (child == "kara") {
          return []() {
              return new Kara();
          };
     }
     // more children here


     // error handling
     return []() {
          return nullptr;
     }
}

// usage example
void createChild()
{
    auto childCreator = getDeferedFactoryFor("paul");
    ChildInterface * paul = childCreator();
    paul->doSomeThing();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will make use of this one day or another, it's great! :)